# How to style monaco editor context menu

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I need to change the css style of the default context menu but I couldn't inspect the classes because it's closed when it out of focus, so if any one knows the classes or know how to adjust the style using javascript can help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you share some of your code you already have?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press F12 to show the console. Input the code and press enter.

```js
setTimeout(() => {debugger;}, 1000);
```

You may open the context menu in 1 second before the browser paused. Then you can inspect the element.

```css
.monaco-menu > .monaco-action-bar.vertical {
  color: red !important;
}
```

But since 0.12 the context menu is under `shadow-root` and the there is no element declare `part` attribute. So in the host there is no way to rewrite the style.

Comment: It is still possible to overwrite the stylesheet of the context menu, 
because the `shadowRoot` isn't `closed`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, where I needed to replace the icons that appear in the completion menu.

From the Network tab of the browser, I opened the file `editor.main.css`.

There, you can see the css selectors, and the embedded svg-xml for the icons.

For example, to replace the icons used for 'methods' or 'functions' in the completion menu, add this to your html (after the Monaco stylesheet is loaded)

```
.monaco-editor .suggest-widget .monaco-list .monaco-list-row .suggest-icon.method::before,
.monaco-editor .suggest-widget .monaco-list .monaco-list-row .suggest-icon.function::before
/* copied from lightbulb */
{ background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a lot of trouble styling it but found the solution finally.

add this to your editor creation to disable the shadow dom.

```js
const editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
useShadowDOM: false,
```

than you can style it like this for example

```css
.monaco-menu {
    background-color: var(--darker);
    color: var(--textColor);
    border: 1px solid var(--borderColor);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.monaco-menu .monaco-menu {
    margin-top: -35px;
    /* Moves the submenu up by 35px */
}

.monaco-menu .action-item {
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.monaco-menu .action-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.monaco-menu .action-item:first-child {
    margin-top: -4px;

}

.monaco-menu .action-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--hover);
}

/* this is the dividers */
.monaco-menu .disabled {
    max-height: 1px;
    background-color: var(--borderColor);
    cursor: default;
}
```

hope this helps!